# why the interface cannot have static member method

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why shouldn't C#(or .NET) allow us to put a static/shared method inside an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062468/why-shouldnt-cor-net-allow-us-to-put-a-static-shared-method-inside-an-interf)

Why we cannot define static method inside interface?

Comment: Why do you need this? Its' limitation of C# language. Use extension method if required.

Comment: As a non related side note, consider editing your display name (i.e. *add* such name) so you can start getting notifications with the `@` sign, right now there's no way to notify you when someone comment on your comment.

Answer (score 7):

From the [top search result](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?dotnet.12.305680.12) in Google:

> Because an interface is a "contract"
>   or an agreement between the consumer
>   (caller) and the provider (callee). An
>   interface describes what and how the
>   calle will provide functionality.
>   There is no need for static members
>   provided by a third party. Static
>   members cannot be overridden by a
>   provider so they do not belong in an
>   interface.
>
> Stefan Rusek
>
> 08 February 2006